# Integrating websphere MQ with boomi

Tags: jms, integration, ibm-mq

We are working on Integrating websphere MQ with boomi,

The Configuration in Boomi for JMS connector is as follows:

**For JMS Connection :**
Authentication Present:
User : adminstrator
password : xxxxx
JMS Server : Websphere MQ
Connection type : Single QM connection
Queue Manager : BoomiQMGR
Channel Name : BoomiSC

**For JMS operation:**
Destination : queue:BoomiQ(where BoomiQ is the Queue Name, "queue:" as mentioned in the boomi Documentation)

But the Problem is, 
with these configuration we encounter the below error in boomi:

*"Test execution of TestProcess completed with errors. Embedded message: Unable to retrieve JMS message; Caused by: JMSCC0005: The specified value 'queue:BoomiQ' is not allowed for 'XMSC_DESTINATION_NAME'."

From what we can tell in reading around this occurs due to WebSphere MQ destination naming restrictions, we are using WEBSPHERE version : WS_MQ_V8.0_TRIAL_FOR_WINDOWS_ML(downloaded from IBM Site)

Can someone help us out on this?

Please suggest if we are missing anything.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem looks to be the format of the Queue Name:  queue:BoomiQ  isn't valid for the WMQ JMS client.

If the Queue on the QueueManager was say MyQueue, then either ensure that MyQueue is passed to JMS or queue:///MyQueue.